# Access overloaded base class method with same name as derived method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm attempting to call a method from a base class with the same name as a method in the derived class. Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Printing from base" << endl;
    }

    void print(int num) {
        cout << "Printing number from base: " << num << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    using Base::print;

public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Printing from derived" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Derived x;

    x.print();
    x.Base::print(1);

    //x.print(1); // Gives a compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to call x.print(1) and get "Printing number from base: 1", that is, automatically call the method which matches the signature, even though it resides in the base class.

Without the `using Base::print;`, I get `error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::print(int)'`, which makes perfect sense due to name hiding.

Thus, I added that line, but now the error is `error: 'void Base::print(int)' is inaccessible`

Why is this the case? I use public inheritance, so I would have thought it was readily available?

As demonstrated in the example, it works fine to manually call `x.Base::print(1);`, but I would like to do it more transparently. Then of course I can re-implement a wrapper to the function in the derived class, but that does not seem very elegant either.

I apologize if this has been covered in an earlier question, I read a bunch of them and found a lot of similar cases, but nothing that helped me.

Comment: Beware! you're printing the text `"Printing from base"` in the `Base::print` and `Derived::print`

Comment: Yeah, just a typo. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placement of the using directive decides about the visibility. Simply place it into the public area and you should be fine:

```
//...
class Derived : public Base
{

public:
    using Base::print;

    void print() {
        cout << "Printing from base" << endl;
    }
};
//...
```

http://ideone.com/06NNk

Comment: +1 Cool, I never knew this. Does that mean that the access level of `Base::print` in `Base` is irrelevant in `Derived`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: No, it does need to be visible to the class containing the using declaration (so public or protected in this case)

Comment: Ah, clever. Exactly what I needed. I'll accept this as soon as the timer allows me to.

Comment: @Nobody: OK, sure, that makes sense. But if the base function is protected, then I can still make it public in the derived class with a public using declaration. That's nice. In particular, `x.f()` would be OK while `x.Base::f()` would not :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right about `f()`, but I do not see, why one would need to make a protected function public (as long as the Base class programmer made the function protected for a good reason).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your functions virtual. Any virtual functions inherited from the base class that aren't overloaded will be called through the derived class.

```
class base 
{
  public:
    virtual void Foo() {}
}

class Derived
{
}

Derived d;
d.foo(); // calls base::foo()
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. Overloading in a derived class is the point.